Geometry Nodes: Translate each instance by bounding box dimension
I want to have each instance touching the curve only on one side.
I can't find out how to use the bounding box dimension to offset the position of each instance.
I made a small blend file with a basic setup I must use.

This is what I am trying to achieve:

Here is the basic setup to start from.

Small disclaimer; I can't use Blender 4.X so please use 3.6 for example..

Whoops! I misunderstood, but future visitors might benefit from the alternative problem so I leave that answer. And as in that answer, take a look at a bounding box:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
The indices for y-axis alternate in pairs, so you can take verts #0 and #2 to get the y-dimension.

Imgur mirror

Imgur mirror

(Blender 3.6.10, ignore the first word in filename)
Blender 4.3
You can modify all instances to reposition their origins, though that's hard before Blender 4.0 as there's no "Split to Instances" node nor a "Repeat" zone. In the Blender 4.3 you have a "For Each" zone that makes it even easier, but probably slower (which can hardly matter because are you going to have millions of objects in a collection to make the iteration overhead matter?):

Imgur mirror

You are amazing! This is exactly what I needed.
There are more nodes than I expected to be needed but that is okay.
Thank you so much!

Hi Markus, I've come back to ask for some more help.. It came to my realization that in the blend file i need this setup to be in, I have multiple collections as input geometry where 'seperate children' must be off. In the file you uploaded the same can be demonstrated by also turning off 'seperate children'. Then you can see the bounding box data is from the first child. I actually need it to use the total bounding box of all children combined. Is there a way to do this? Please let me know if you need more explanation.

@Ramon if you want to use a common bounding box to offset them all, then they won't all touch the curve with one side anymore, is that what you want? Also how do you spawn them if they're not separated? If you separate for spawning but don't for bounding box, you get this: https://i.imgur.com/IPYcgYA.png and result: https://i.imgur.com/vwMFYQu.png

For this example they don't have to be seperated. As in my project file I have multiple collections to use instead of multiple objects to use. Let me show you what I mean. Turn of the 'seperate children' and you see it is aligned on the curve by using the bounding box of the first child. https://imgur.com/a/1YsRSqt But I need it to use the total bounding box of all children combined. Like this: https://imgur.com/a/TQB6lqR

@Ramon maybe like this then: https://i.imgur.com/WTHzu76.png and https://i.imgur.com/IM4qva8.png

Hi Markus, thanks again for the reply. That setup works when all instances have the same dimensions. Which is not the case in my project. https://imgur.com/a/N5HYU8a Here is the blend file which comes closest to my use case. If you'd have the time to look at it I would really appreciate it. https://blend-exchange.com/b/S53xeY7a/

@Ramon my last screenshot was on your file, where the instances don't have the same dimensions and you can even see that on the screenshot

Yes I can see that. I mean when using different collections which have children with different sizes. In my previous comment there is a blend file with a setup which uses more collections as input instances.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I checked the result of Bounding Box node with Set Geometry Randomization operator (it doesn't work on 3.6 unfortunately) and the indices are stable. This makes the setup much easier. Take a look at a bounding box of anything with x-thickness:

Imgur mirror (SE image hosting has problems)
Even indices are on the left side, and odd indices are on the right side. So the strategy is to create bounding boxes, delete all but first corner for them, realize them, and now you have as many points as there were bounding boxes, so as many points as there were instances, and indices match. Then do the same for 2nd corners and sample their positions by index to calculate x-dimension:

Imgur mirror
The Absolute node isn't actually necessary there, as fixed bounding box indices ensure #1 vertex is always to the right of #0. The "Mix" node might be confusing. It's role is to sum two halves of accumulated distances, because each offset is half previous bounding box and half current bbox.

Imgur mirror

(Blender 3.6.10)

It's insane how they haven't made geometry fields available yet.... this bounding box thing should be ridiculously easy.

Hi Markus, thank you for your quick response!
I am not sure if we are on the same page though.
I don't need the blocks to touch eachother, I need them to touch the curve with one side only.
So in theory I want them to translate half of their individual size. In my original post you can see a screenshot of what I am trying to achieve.

@Ramon Ohhh that should be simpler :D Though now that I look because I used a bounding box of a curve it doesn't show Y/Z differences so I need to redo that screenshot, might as well write a separate answer then
