Geometry nodes: translate asymmetrical instances with their Y+ bounding box value relative to points position
This is a follow up / more in depth question about translating instances by their bounding box size.
I would like to translate each instance left with their Y+ value relative of the point position so they will align left to the curve.
This is the basic setup:

And this is the desired outcome:

Is there any way to do this (in blender 3.6) using geometry nodes?
Here is the basic setup blend file you can use:

Thanks in advance for any help!

But the objects seem to be not centered on the curve, at least not all - so half the size of the bounding boxes will not align them all. I'm not at a PC right now so I cannot write a proper answer. But what you need to do is get the maximum Y values of the bounding boxes and subtract them from the objects' positions to align them.

I think this question is very very similar to this one: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/327302/geometry-nodes-translate-each-instance-by-bounding-box-dimension

@GordonBrinkmann, you are totally right. Half of the boundingbox won't match indeed. Subtracting the maximum Y value from the point position should work. The problem is that I don't know how to do it per individual instance.

@DanielMöller, yes it is. It is actually a follow up question.

The other answer totally tells you how to do it... just replace the average of the box with one of its max or min X.

Here, I made a node group that makes it easy to get bounding box for random instances.
All you need is to subtract the minimum or maximum from the bounding box in the direction you want:

Geometry nodes
In the example, I subtracted the X from the left side of the BBox (because that value is usually negative). This displaces the instances to the right (if you want to the left, subtract the max).

The Random Instance BBox group
This group wraps a random selection of an instance and returns its bounding box:

The Instance BBox group
This group returns the bounding box for a given instance.
It explores the fact that:

The bounding box has 8 points
The lowest point in the bounding box has index 0 (thus in the realized geometry, we multiply the instance index by 8)
The highest point in the bounding box has index 7 (thus we add 7 to the index)


File


Wow, thank you for the great write up! It makes it so much easier to understand what is going on. This is the setup I was looking for. Thank you
